# How do I get a webview in Kivy for Python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I tried nearly everything but every webview module is either deprecated or is just not working. Just a simple webview in a Kivy windows. A webview which opens a Url and people don't have to open the Url extra in the Browser.

I tried the following webview modules: webview-Buildung wheel did not run successfully
Kivy garden webview-is no longer in pip
Kivy engine is no longer in pip
Kivy-webengine is no longer in pip
webengine doesn't work on my system. The module is installed but the system doesn't find it. I installed it from pip.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.